# What abilities can Fiora's Riposte parry?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm starting to play Fiora more and more, and I've noticed that her parry is a little inconsistent. For example, I've blocked some abilities you would expect to be blocked such as Gangplank's Parley and Miss Fortune's Double Shot, but I've also seen people parry Karthus's Requiem. Is there any way to know what Riposte can and cannot block?

Answer (score 2):

According to the description of the skill [Reposte](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Fiora):

> Fiora poises to strike in the target direction and then enters a defensive stance, parrying all incoming non-turret damage and hostile crowd control effects for the next 0.75 seconds.

This indicates that all damage, attacks and abilities are parried. 
[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/3gxjsv/what_can_fiora_riposte/) Reddit thread indicates that there is a consensus that this is indeed the case.

Comment: It's not quite accurate though. It'll parry any attack which procs on-hit effects, even ultimates like Warwick's Infinite Duress, or even Fiora's own Blade Waltz. (Only the first hit, though)

Answer (score 0):

It works against all abilities that enhance basic attacks, such as talon's noxian diplomacy.
it also works against abilities that apply on hit effects, like gankplanks parrley, and ezreal's mystic shot.
I don't think it can block any other abilities, and it definitely can't block requiem. That is probably a banshee's vale spell shield, not riposte